# WorkManager : Cannot access database on the main thread since it may potentially lock the UI for a long period of time

Tags: android, android-room, android-workmanager

I got error when I use WorkManager.

> Cannot access database on the main thread since it may potentially
>   lock the UI for a long period of time.

My Code

```
val x = WorkManager.getInstance().getStatusesByTag(vm.workTag)
x.observeForever { }
```

If i dont use method observe all work fine

My Log

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot access database on the main thread since it may potentially lock the UI for a long period of time.
at androidx.room.RoomDatabase.assertNotMainThread(RoomDatabase.java:223)
at androidx.room.RoomDatabase.beginTransaction(RoomDatabase.java:269)
at androidx.work.impl.model.WorkSpecDao_Impl$11.compute(WorkSpecDao_Impl.java:928)
at androidx.work.impl.model.WorkSpecDao_Impl$11.compute(WorkSpecDao_Impl.java:914)
at androidx.lifecycle.ComputableLiveData$2.run(ComputableLiveData.java:101)
at androidx.arch.core.executor.testing.InstantTaskExecutorRule$1.executeOnDiskIO(InstantTaskExecutorRule.java:38)
at androidx.arch.core.executor.ArchTaskExecutor.executeOnDiskIO(ArchTaskExecutor.java:96)
at androidx.arch.core.executor.ArchTaskExecutor$2.execute(ArchTaskExecutor.java:53)
at androidx.lifecycle.ComputableLiveData$1.onActive(ComputableLiveData.java:70)
at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData$ObserverWrapper.activeStateChanged(LiveData.java:418)
at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.observeForever(LiveData.java:214)
at androidx.lifecycle.MediatorLiveData$Source.plug(MediatorLiveData.java:141)
at androidx.lifecycle.MediatorLiveData.onActive(MediatorLiveData.java:118)
at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData$ObserverWrapper.activeStateChanged(LiveData.java:418)
at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.observeForever(LiveData.java:214)
at org.kadance.ftvideo.view.VideoPlayerActivity.onCreate(VideoPlayerActivity.kt:827)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
at androidx.test.runner.MonitoringInstrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(MonitoringInstrumentation.java:667)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
```

Comment: So what's inside `observeForever`? Nothing at all? otherwise post the relevant code.

Comment: observeForever it's just method of androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.
when I use other method "observe()" I got such error.

Comment: No I mean, is there a code inside in that `observeForever{ // code here ?}` or `observer{ \\ code here? }`? Cuz I am assuming that you omitted that code to simplify your question. But to be safe post also your Worker subclass that has database logic.

Comment: Worker is here
https://github.com/Kadanza/Ling3/blob/master/ftvideo/src/main/java/org/kadance/ftvideo/view/VideoToSpeekWorker.kt

Activity with observed worker
https://github.com/Kadanza/Ling3/blob/master/ftvideo/src/main/java/org/kadance/ftvideo/view/VideoPlayerActivity.kt

Comment: observeForever{ } is  empty

Comment: What is inside this `d()` ? I am having trouble following the code in my phone!

Comment: d()  just static function what contains Log.d("Tag", ""). 

I remove this in next commit.

Comment: Code with some error. Only module FtVideo work now.  If you want run this code need run throw test methods in Starter class https://github.com/Kadanza/Ling3/blob/master/ftvideo/src/androidTest/java/org/kadance/ftvideo/Starter.kt

just run method openVideo

Comment: Ok I see, by the way I notice a suspicious code at [line 107](https://github.com/Kadanza/Ling3/blob/master/ftvideo/src/main/java/org/kadance/ftvideo/view/VideoPlayerActivity.kt#L107). Database transaction should be done in a Background thread, this might not be related to the code you posted but I hope you might also look at that.

Comment: I have room db and i allow work in MainThread.
In  DataRepo i have Database 
Room.databaseBuilder(context, AppDatabase::class.java, "database2")
                .allowMainThreadQueries()
                .build()

https://github.com/Kadanza/Ling3/blob/master/data/src/main/java/org/kadance/data/data/db/DataRepo.kt

Comment: WorkManager don't touch my Database, i think WorkManager has own room database

Comment: Yes WorkManager creates a database so that it can store states. Located in `data/data/<package>/databases/androix.work.workdb`

Comment: Do I wrong use WorkManager? it should be not main thread? How allow workmanager works in mainThread? My db can work in main thread

Comment: I don't think you are wrong because we can queue a Worker in the MainThread. Your issue is a bit odd since it only occurs when you use `observe` as what you said.

Comment: androidTestImplementation 'androidx.arch.core:core-testing:2.0.0-beta01' case to this error.
I remove InstantTaskExecutorRule  from my test class and it works now
  
    var rule: TestRule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()

Comment: Cool, it would be nice if you put that in the answer section so that if someone stumbled with the same issue your answer will be able to help other people :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I run Activity throw test class what have InstantTaskExecutorRule.

androidTestImplementation 'androidx.arch.core:core-testing:2.0.0-beta01' case to this error.

I remove InstantTaskExecutorRule from my test class and it works now